# how to set up multiple caller ID for imessaging

Tags: messages

how do I add another caller ID (ie existing email address) to the list of addresses I can send imessages from? It shows multiple email addresses to receive imessages, but only one to send from.

Answer (score 1):

Settings > Messages > Send & Receive

[image]

Add Another Email won't let you add any address associated with another Apple ID